# If $f(x)=g(t)$ and $x=t^2$ what are $f'$ and $f''$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

If I have $f(x)=g(t)$ and $x=t^2$, can we conclude from this what $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$ are in terms of g(t) and its derivatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if $x=t^2\Rightarrow t=\sqrt{x}$ thus:

$f'(x)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}g(t(x))=\frac{\partial t(x)}{\partial x}g'(t)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}g'(t)$, now we apply the chain rule again:

$f''(x)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}g'(t))=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\frac{1}{2}x^{-\frac{1}{2}})g'(t)+\frac{1}{4x}g''(t)=-\frac{1}{4}x^{-\frac{3}{2}}g'(t)+\frac{1}{4x}g''(t)$

Comment: No. For one thing, $t$ could well be $-\sqrt x$. For another, and this is more technical, it could be that *sometimes* $t$ is $\sqrt x$, and other times it is $-\sqrt x$. This can be quite problematic when differentiation is involved, and it is not elementary to rule this possibility out. The best thing in order to avoid getting into difficult issues is to avoid this approach.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's just a composition of functions. $f(x)=g(t)$, $x=t^2$, then we have
$$
y=f(x),\ x=u(t)=t^2,
$$
so
$$
z=(f\circ u)(t)=g(t).
$$
Then
$$
\frac{dz}{dt}=\frac{dz}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}.
$$
Since
$$
\frac{dz}{dx}=\frac{df}{dx}\ \text{and}\ \frac{dz}{dt}=\frac{dg}{dt},
$$
so
$$
\frac{dg}{dt}=\frac{df}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}=2t\frac{df}{dx}
$$
i.e., 
$$
f^\prime=\frac{1}{2t}g^\prime.
$$
I think it should be like this. Any way the chain rule applies here.